# How do I add a Form to my Windows Forms project when all I have is the option for Inherited Form?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want to create a blank form in Visual Studio C#.

However, all I can create is an inherited Form, why is that?

[image: See picture of form creation]

On the web, all I can find is a tutorial where they have the blank form option. Why don't I have it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the start menu and look for Visual Studio Installer (for VS 2015 or later).  Run the program.

Find the Modify setting under the More menu: 
[image: Visual Studio Installer Modify Menu]

Make sure you have the ".NET desktop development" box checked.
[image: Visual Studio Installer Workload menu]

Perform any necessary Visual Studio restarts and you should then have the option for a Windows Form when you select `Add...` from Solution Explorer within a Windows Forms project.